# How to get information from 1 method to another. c#

Tags: c#

I started doing c# and now I'm having some issues. This is an assignment for the class I am taking. First I created a program that worked, but then I realised I missed out on the whole method thing. So I'm trying to redo the stuff. So basically I'm doing a program that converts fahrenheit to celsius, based on what the user types. So far I have this:

```cs
 static double  FahrenheittoCelsius(double fahr, double cel)
        {

            fahr = (cel * 9) / 5 + 32;
            return fahr;

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            double cel = 0;
            double fahr = 97;

            double max_temp = 170.6;
            double min_temp = 163.4;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the sauna! We will find the optimal temperature for you! ");



            do
            {
                Console.Write("Please type in Fahrenheit: ");


                try
                {

                  fahr = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.Write("Only numbers please!");
                    continue;
                }

                if (fahr >= max_temp)
                {
                    Console.Write("The temperature you typed is {0} Celsius, type a lower temperature!", Math.Round(cel, 1));

                }

                else if (fahr <= min_temp)
                {
                    Console.Write("Temperature you typed is {0} Celsius, type a higher temperature!", Math.Round(cel, 1));

                }

                else if (fahr > min_temp && fahr < max_temp)
                {
                    Console.Write("Now the temperature is {0} celsius and now the temperature is optimal!", Math.Round(cel, 1));
                }

            } while (fahr > min_temp != fahr < max_temp);



            Console.ReadLine();
```

So excuse my halfass translate since it was all in Swedish.
But my problem is I can't get the equation "fahr = (cel * 9) / 5 + 32 return fahr;" to my try and catch, which worked in my other program (where I didn't use the method). I can't get it to work.

All help is appreciated

Comment: When you say `I can't get it to work`, what is the specific problem? Is it throwing an exception? Giving the wrong result?

Comment: It does not _work_, because it is not even _called_.

Comment: You have 2 functions: `Main(string[] args)` and `FahrenheittoCelsius(double fahr, double cel)`.
Your program calls the Main function and performs the commands in that function. In order to use your formula which is found in the other function, you have to call it. You call a function by declaring its name and passing any parameters required in this case

    cel = FahrenheittoCelsius(fahr, cel)

However, your FahrenheittoCelsius method is wrong maybe you should see it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to programming!  You have several small issues with your code:

First looking at your method:

```
static double  FahrenheittoCelsius(double fahr, double cel)
{    
     fahr = (cel * 9) / 5 + 32;
     return fahr;
}
```

- The method name should be FahrenheitToCelsius -- each word starting
  with a capital letter.
- According to the title of the method you are converting fahrenheit to
  celsius. based on that you would only need to pass a fehrenheit and
  return a celsius.  You are passing both but then returning
  fehrenheit!?
- The formula you have is also wrong.  It should be (F − 32) × 5/9 so code-wise:

  var cel = (fahr - 32) * 5 / 9;

  return cel;

Then in your main you need to call this method

cel = FahrenheitToCelsius(fahr);

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        double cel = 0;
        double fahr = 97;

        double max_temp = 170.6;
        double min_temp = 163.4;
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the sauna! We will find the optimal temperature for you! ");



        do
        {
            Console.Write("Please type in Fahrenheit: ");


            try
            {

              fahr = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
              cel = FahrenheitToCelsius(fahr);


            }
            catch
            {
                Console.Write("Only numbers please!");
                continue;
            }
```

Comment: Nvm im the stupid one, i wrote the wrong thing, gimme a sec. Okey well it still doesnt work. A local or parameter named Cel cannot be declared in this scope. The cel = FahrenheitToCelsius didnt work either D:

Comment: @CptDubb Sounds like you are good to go, if so, please accept the answer.

Comment: @CptDubb welcome to StackOverflow. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is written how to accept an answer if it helped you to solve your problem